# Pane doesn't adhere to pref size

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am trying to use some sort of container like a "div" in JavaFX to divide the screen into different partitions. With the code below, I was wondering why the canvas takes out the whole screen instead of being 10x20 pixels.

```
package sample;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Scene;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setTitle("Window Title");
        TextField textField = new textField();
        stackPane root = new StackPane();
        Pane canvas = new Pane();
        canvas.setPrefSize(10, 20);
        canvas.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
        root.getChildren().addAll(canvas, textField);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: in future questions, please post a [mcve] - that is an example that you verified is compiling and running - vs. an ad-hoc snippet as this (wont compile)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only set the preferred size for `canvas`. This tells the parent that it should set the size to these dimensions, *if that's possible according to it's own layout constraints.*

In this case `StackPane`'s property to attempt to achieve a size as close as it's own size takes precedent. It can do this, since you do not specify a `max`/`min` constraint. You can tell it to use the same values as for the `pref` size using `Region.USE_PREF_SIZE`:

```
canvas.setPrefSize(10, 20);
canvas.setMinSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
canvas.setMaxSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
```

Comment: technically correct - but usually not the real story (as I know that you know :). All min/pref/max are sizing _hints_ that a parent layout respects (or not) at its own rules. So most of the time the task is to find a suitable layout (OP's one that respects prefWidth). In that vane, Stackpane is rarely what an app needs.